# Change CSS using Jquery not dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have one Jquery UI slider and drop-down menu, based on selected and option tags. The slider changes the border width of a CSS box (this works fine dynamically). The drop-down menu must change the border-style property (this doesn't work as it should).

When the option is changed, the changes do not appear instantly, as the slider does, but the changes from the drop-down menu appear after the slider has been moved

Here is the slider code:

```
$(function() {
$("#border_slider").slider({
value: 0,
min: 0,
max: 20,
step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $("#border_amount").val(ui.value );
    $("#plugin_previewbox").css("border", (ui.value) + "px "+$("#select-border").val()+" #000000");
    }
});
    $("#border_amount").val($("#border_slider").slider("value"));
});
```

And here is the jquery for the drop-down options:

```
$('#select-border').change(function() {
var BorderStyle = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
$("#plugin_previewbox").removeAttr("border");
$("#plugin_previewbox").css("border", $("#border_amount").val() + "px " + BorderStyle + " #000000");
});
```

Here is the HTML of the drop-down:

```
< select id="select-border" ><br>
< option selected="selected" value="solid" >solid< /option ><br>
< option value="dotted" >dotted< /option ><br>
< option value="dashed" >dashed< /option ><br>
... and so on....<br>
< /select >
```

Any ideas why this does not work?

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: Nope, just the drop-down not updating. The update is viewable after the slider is moved after the option is selected

Comment: Any chance for a js fiddle which reproduces this?

Comment: Yes, good idea, I will make a demo in a few minutes

Comment: Strange - here it works, but on my computer it does not. I only have copy-pasted the code.. https://jsfiddle.net/jrf8wjbh/2/

Answer (score 0):

It does work, but the initial value of border is 0. So you can't see it.

Set the first border_slider value to 1 (or even 10).